# Subsetting a dataframe based on another dataframe column value in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe, df:

```
studID    Name
023       John
283       Mary
842       Jacob
211       Amy
```

and another dataframe, df_2:

```
studID
023
999
100
211
575
```

I want to subset the first dataframe, df so that it only contains the row values which the studID exists in the dataframe df_2.

So i would get:

```
studID    Name
023       John
211       Amy
```

This dataframe would only contain John and Amy record since their studID is found in df_2.

I tried the following:

```
df_3 <- df[intersect(df$studID, df_2$studID),]
```

But I'm getting N/A values.

Comment: `df_3 <- df[df$studID %in% df_2$studID,]`